# Once a store is registered, automatically creating a landmark on Google Maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps

I am trying to have a store register with their address, which once registered will automatically create a landmark on google maps of the location. How should I go about doing this? I have been using Ruby on Rails for the majority on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geokit is fairly easy to implement.  If you are just beginning to use the Google mapping API, I would recommend starting here: https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3.

Once you get it setup properly, you can do something like this in your controller...

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
if @event.is_geocoded?
  @map = GMap.new("map_div", 'map')
  @map.control_init(:large_map => true, :map_type => false)
  @map.center_zoom_init(@event.latlon,12)
  @map.overlay_init(GMarker.new(@event.latlon, :title => @event.name, :info_window => @event.address_for_map_popup))
end
```

In your view, something like this:

```
- if @map
  - initialize_map
  = @map.to_html.html_safe
  = @map.div(:width => 478, :height => 400).html_safe
```

It is the `GMarker` that creates the map marker and `overlay_init` that overlays it on top of the map.

Answer (score 0):

So the best way would probably be to store their location in a database (or translate to coordinates first then store in database). From there you can use something like google maps javascript api to drop pins onto a map you generate.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: So you are saying that I should use the Javascript API to have my map add a pin to the area on the map that relates to the address of the stores that are stored in the database

Comment: Yes. You might check out geokit as mentioned above.. I've never used it but it look like it implements what I was talking about. The javascript api is pretty good